# Get access to the calculator with java

Tags: java, system, calculator

I'm working on a java project and I want to attach a calculator from the operating system. But I haven't any idea to do that. If there any idea it would be a great help.

Comment: What do you mean by "get access" ? Just run it ?

Comment: calculator is not a part of computer, it is a part of operating system. Different operating systems keep calculator with different file names. User can uninstall system calculator and install own one.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov thanks for your comment and I've edited my question

Comment: @c0der has your problem solved and any way to help me ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("[path]\calc.exe");
```

To open the calculator. But beware: The only way that you can communicate with applications you open this way is through the Process streams: in/out/err (assuming calc is set up to communicate as such)

Answer (score 1):

in cmd you can type `calc.exe` and run it, to run calculator through the java use the `java.lang.Runtime` class to run commands:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

more details about Shell Commands in java [read this...](https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-java/)

Comment: Thanks for your help with resources 

Comment: Do you have any idea to get the calculator in linux